Kubectl error : [memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list
I'm new to Kubernetes and I'm trying to set up a local cluster using k3d. Here are the steps I've taken:

Installed k3d and kubectl.
Created a cluster using k3d cluster create -a 2.
Switched to the cluster context using kubectl config use-context k3d-k3s-default.
However, when I run kubectl cluster-info to check the connection to the cluster, I encounter the following error:

couldn't get current server API group list: Get "https://host.docker.internal:55345/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp 192.168.1.24:55345: connectex: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

I'm unsure how to resolve this issue. Can anyone help me understand what might be causing this error and how to fix it? Thank you in advance!

This happens usually because of dns or networking. The issue is with the host.docker.internal. you can change host.docker.internal to 127.0.0.1 in $HOME/. kube/config, you an probably reach it. Or by creating a new cluster like k3d cluster create mycluster --api-port localhost:5443

it worked ! i changed the host.docker.internal to 127.0.0.1 and now its working ! thank u so much but do you have any idea what caused this problem ? i didn't create the config file it was automatically created so i have to resolve the DNS issue on my own each time ? thanks for your help tho

usually because of the dns resolution. I post it as answer.

This happens usually because of dns or networking. The issue is with the host.docker.internal. you can change host.docker.internal to 127.0.0.1 in $HOME/.kube/config, you can reach it. Or by creating a new cluster like
k3d cluster create mycluster --api-port localhost:5443


for anyone like me, using windows as host for docker, setting the port on "--api-port localhost:6550" while creating the k3d cluster, did the trick, and now kubectl can connect flawlessly
